# Why do I see a purple then black screen when booting and a 'failed to load module "nv"' error when running startx in tty1?

Tags: boot, nvidia

I just installed **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** from a USB stick. After the Installation (XP works besides)
grub shows both OS. When trying to start there is the purple Screen for some seconds, and then the Screen goes black, but with backlight. No mouse no cursor.

With <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F2</kbd> I get into `tty1`. Trying startx I get to the Messages that state:

> failed to load module "nv" and some other NVIDIA related error messages.

Well, from the stick without Installation on **HDD** everything was great, but now I dont get into the **GUI**.

Maybe there is some help for me? I tried updating of the Drivers and some other things, (ppa) 
but it does not work

Comment: Can you load the text only version? I.E., Server?

Answer (score 0):

nv is deprecated open source driver.
Make sure you don't have it in xorg.conf, and try blacklisting it with:

> `echo "blacklist nv" | sudo tee -a "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"`